# Including moment-holiday into Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, momentjs

I'm using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) in Angular by importing it as `import * as moment from 'moment';` and added [moment-holiday](https://github.com/kodie/moment-holiday) to the application dependencies, as well as the typings.  So now moment autocompletes with moment-holiday's API, but the `moment-holiday` package isn't being loaded so the methods are not found, and using `import 'moment-holiday'` where I've added it in the `AppComponent` doesn't seem to add it to the `moment` object.

I was hoping to be able to run: `moment.modifyHolidays.set('Canada/BC');` to include the Canadian holidays, as well as, BC holidays, but you can't just add it to the `index.html` since `moment` hasn't loaded yet and it's required.

How would I include the `moment-holiday` dependency after moment has been loaded,  so I can setup a config/service with the holidays I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works in an angular cli project as such:

1) add the following to the scripts array of your angular-cli.json file:

`"./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
 "./node_modules/moment-holiday/build/moment-holiday-us.min.js"`

2) In the file where you want to import moment-holiday, instead just add `declare var moment: any;` at the top of that file. Don't import moment or moment-holiday. Then use this library as normal: `moment().holidaysBetween(<some_moment_object>)`

EDIT: The reason why this is not too too bad, is that npmjs.com has runkit integration and you can test your code there: https://npm.runkit.com/moment-holiday

get it running, and just transfer the code to your main project

Comment: Have you tried fixing your issue? This may fix your issue